# Edit/Save Loses the "Edit Tags" Link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, inline-tag-editor

Steps to reproduce:

1. Browse to a question
2. Mouse over to the right of the tags to confirm there is an "edit tags" link
3. Click the "edit" link (not "edit tags")
4. Click "Save edits"
5. Mouse over to the right of the tags to confirm there is no longer an "edit tags" link

Comment: @kiam This appears to be the *opposite* problem.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: If I had meant the review page, then my #1 step would have been "Click the Review link".

Comment: I apologize: The question is somehow related, but it is surely not a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111145/the-edit-tags-link-available-to-10k-users-is-visible-in-the-review-page-only-a). Hopefully, both the issues will be solved at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue in the current build of our network sites. If it remains a problem please let me know.